# invoke a view-method from a controller task joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component, joomla-task

I am trying to create Joomla2.5 component via MVC. I want to direct controller to mydisplay() method defined in view.xml.php from task=jump in entry point. Thanks.

**/ROOT/components/com_api/views/api/view.xml.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla view library
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

/**
 * XML View class for the Api Component
 */
class ApiViewApi extends JView
{
// Overwriting JView display method

function mydisplay($tpl = null)
{
//echo JRequest::getVar('task');

    //$this->get('Ister');
    // Assign data to the view
    $this->msg = $this->get('xCredentials');

    // Check for errors.
    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
    {
        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
        return false;
    }

    // Display the view
    parent::display($tpl);
}



}
?>
```

**ROOT/components/com_api/api.php(entry point controller)**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by Api
$controller = JController::getInstance('Api');


// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task'));

$controller->redirect();

?>
```

**ROOT/components/com_api/controller.php(controller with task=jump)**

```
<?php

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
/**
 * Api Component Controller
 */
class ApiController extends JController
{
function jump()
  {
    //parent::display();


/* invoke mydisplay method from view.xml.php, located in views*/

  }
}
```

How do i call mydisplay() method in view.xml.php after executing a task=jump?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$view = $this->getView('Api', 'xml');
$view->setModel($this->getModel('Api'), true);
$view->display();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try put this in jump function of the controller

```
$view = $this->getView('API');
$view->mydisplay();
```